# Lubricating squeaky European cabinet hinges

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges, squeak

Our kitchen cabinets are about 5 years old now and starting to squeak, some of them awfully. They have European-style hinges (KraftMaid is the cabinet brand and I guess these are Blum hinges). I'm an old hand with good old WD-40 and the trusty straw, but not these sorts of hinges. For the life of me, I can't cure the squeak. I have squirted WD in every crevice where I think there are moving parts, but the squeak persists. What am I missing here? Could someone point out where to stick the straw in these darn hinges, please? I hope disassembly isn't required to be able to get at the right spot in these hinges!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be a matter of *where*, but of *what*. WD-40 isn't a great lubricant in some cases. It's very light and may not work on the nylon parts. It may also dissolve any actual grease that was present.

Maybe try something with Teflon, lithium, or silicone, or use basic 3-in-1 household oil.

Comment: I went with 3-in-1 initially but had trouble with drips on the vertical surfaces. I'll take a look at the other alternates you suggest.

Comment: Those hinges come off easily. You could lay them flat and put a single drop at the top and bottom of the articulation points. It doesn't take more than that. Put masking tape on the cabinet frame to mark the current position.